# Extjs hbox with vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have an hbox layout container that holds 2 panels, when the panels exceeds the height of the container there is no vertical scrollbar.

I want the scroll bar to appear on the parent  hbox panel and not the child items.

can it be done?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: is the content of the panel inside clipped?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add `autoScroll: true` to the parent panel with the hbox layout.

Comment: @AMember Can you post your code so we can see what it looks like? Hard to try to debug something we can't see... (Or better yet you can show a jsfiddle =p)

Comment: yes, I will make an example and post it as soon as I am back in the office.

Comment: Never got back to the office?